# Probability Iteration

Tags: probability

Say that the random variable $T$ can take on discrete ages {$a_i$}$_{i=1,..,n}$, $(a_1 < a_2< \ldots <a_n)$ where $T$ is the age of death then

$P(T=a_j)=P(T\neq a_1 \cap T \neq a_2 \cap $ ... $ \cap $ $T=a_j)$

How do I show that:

$P(T\neq a_1 \cap T \neq a_2 \cap $ ... $ \cap $ $T=a_j)=$

$P(T\neq a_1)P(T\neq a_2| T \neq a_1)P(T \neq a_3)P(T \neq a_1 \cap a_2)$ .. $P(T=a_j|T  \neq a_1 \cap...\cap a_{j-1})$

I have tried iterating the law of conditional probability but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: You get proper spacing if you use `\ldots` instead of `...` and `\mid` instead of `|`. Also note that you can get displayed equations by using double dollar signs instead of single dollar signs. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a reference and tutorial for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: It's not clear (to me) what $P(T\ne a_1\cap a_2)$ means.

Comment: Apologies, I've edited the OP so it should be clearer now. It means the probability of not dying at ages $a_1$ and $a_2$, the smallest two ages